# Progress Bar overlapped by image

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I want to have an image which is overlapping a progress bar. Its basically a thermometer that shows the certain progress until a point. I've managed to flip the progress bar vertical and know about opacity, but I'm not sure how to implement it to get my desired result. I'm doing it using laravel. Here is the basic code for my idea:

```
<style> 
.progress {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    position: 4px;

    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    opacity:0.9;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    70% Complete (danger)
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is something like the image below where i'm using the progress bar to fill up the thermometer in that image

[Thermometer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuEEr.gif)

Would really appreciate the help

Comment: Can we have the url to the thermometer image. I want to make that as a background image and check

Comment: try to add div container with `position:  relative` and inside put progress bar and image with `position: absolute`. Use something like `top: 10px`, `left: 10px` for adjustment of image css

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa i've renamed the image to 'thermometer image'. Also here's the url-> https://www.google.com.au/search?q=thermometer+progress+bar&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUr-uxtYjUAhWEipQKHToDAPMQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=613#imgdii=6xHK6Xc4aIQ_RM:&imgrc=iMluyLNPAJRU2M:

Comment: @Meroz yeah, guess i'll try that way